# Synonymize [iso-639-2] and [iso-639]

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonym-process

[There are several standards in ISO 639 family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639), but they all are pretty much about the same and are rather rare a topic. So I don't think each one warrants a separate tag.

The specific incentive was [Convert ISO 639-1 to ISO 639-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34302586/convert-iso-639-1-to-iso-639-2) that would otherwise need two tags, [iso-639-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iso-639-2) and [iso-639-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iso-639-3), the latter of which doesn't exist.

So, I instead created the umbrella [iso-639](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iso-639) and am suggesting to merge the former into it.